# failed to send Message to channel errors in spring-cloud rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring-cloud-stream/2.1.3.RELEASE.
I want to enable auto-bind-dlq to write in dlq queue the message who generate an error.

my listener:

```
@SuppressWarnings("boxing")
    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)

    public void handle(RabbitInput input) throws Exception {
        //  final RabbitInput dataFromRabbit = message.getPayload();

        try {
//DO SOME
System.out.println("do some");

        } catch (final Exception ex) {

            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("error");
            //throw ex;
        }
    }
```

my application.properties include:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.max-attempts=2
```

but when i try, it iterate two times in //do some then delete message from origin queue and doesn't write message in dlq queue, console error is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'insp.core.notification.events.errors'; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Retry Policy Exhausted
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: If the queue already exists you must delete it first before enabling DLQ.

Comment: Thank you Gary. i solved it!!! have a good day.